# Making BuddyPress Activity Stream (Post Type) Featured Images Clickable

Tags: php, functions, buddypress

I've added woocommerce product postings as a post type to BuddyPress Activity stream via this code in bp-custom.php file:

```
    <?php

add_post_type_support( 'product', 'buddypress-activity' );
 
function customize_page_tracking_args() {
    // Check if the Activity component is active before using it.
    if ( ! bp_is_active( 'activity' ) ) {
        return;
    }
 
    bp_activity_set_post_type_tracking_args( 'product', array(
        'component_id'             => buddypress()->blogs->id,
        'action_id'                => 'new_product_page',
        'bp_activity_admin_filter' => __( 'Published a new product', 'custom-domain' ),
        'bp_activity_front_filter' => __( 'Pages', 'custom-domain' ),
        'contexts'                 => array( 'activity', 'member' ),
        'activity_comment'         => true,
        'bp_activity_new_post'     => __( '%1$s posted a new <a href="%2$s">product</a>', 'custom-textdomain' ),
        'bp_activity_new_post_ms'  => __( '%1$s posted a new <a href="%2$s">product</a>, on the site %3$s', 'custom-textdomain' ),
        'position'                 => 100,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_init', 'customize_page_tracking_args' );

?>
```

Further, I've managed to get the product's featured images to display in the activity stream for the product post types via this code in my functions.php file:

```
function icondeposit_bp_activity_entry_meta() {
 
    if ( bp_get_activity_object_name() == 'blogs' && bp_get_activity_type() == 'new_product_page' ) {?>
        <?php
        global $wpdb, $post, $bp;
        $theimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(  get_post_thumbnail_id( bp_get_activity_secondary_item_id() ), 'medium' );
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $theimg[0]; ?>" >
 
    <?php }
 
}
```

What I'm simply trying to do is make the product featured images shown in the activity stream clickable (link to the product post).